# Amazon Product API - Error! TooManyRequests on AMS ScratchPad

Tags: amazon-mws, aws-api-gateway, scratchpad, paapi

I was approved for the Amazon Product API, and am doing a couple test calls in ScratchPad, and it continually comes back with the error:

`Error! TooManyRequests The request was denied due to request throttling. Please verify the number of requests made per second to the Amazon Product Advertising API.`

I've never once received a good response. I have chatted into their support for over a week, and no one there is any help, and just says 'it looks fine, I don't know why you're getting that response'

- I've only made about 10 calls total, via ScratchPad. Maybe only about 3/day.
- I have more than 3 qualifying sales in the last 30 days.
  [image: my sales]
- Keys are more than 72 hours old. Even made a second pair of keys, waited 3 days, and they still don't work.
- Applied for API usage and keys about 2 weeks ago, so hasn't been disabled due to 30 days of no sales attributed to API.

Here is what I'm inputting into ScratchPad:
[image: scratchpad]

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't fixed yet with the scratchpad. It is well known that there is no solution for that problem at the moment.
There are 2 good manuals out there for other Amazon affiliate usages: [Workaround 1](https://www.wp-amazon-plugin.com/knowledge-base/asa2/amazon-api/amazon-pa-api-issue-error-requestthrottled-you-are-submitting-requests-too-quickly/) and [Workaround 2](https://mintedempire.com/fix-amazon-api-429-too-many-requests/).

I think you should switch like in the Workarounds described. The API can't handle that by now.

I know that isn't the answer you want to here, but it could help others facing the same issue. I will keep the answer updated, if a final solution is coming up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into these. If this is a well known issue, I wish Amazon would 'know' it as well - they seemed clueless when I chatted them at least 30 times about this.

Comment: You are welcome. Could you mark this question as correct, that others not need to chat with the amazon support ;) I know this is really annoying. Good look in further projects.

Comment: @Etienne Kaiser is any update on the problem?